# Посчитать сумму значений в массиве

Tags: php

Есть у меня массив с данными. Как посчитать сумму значений? Пробовал функцию `array_sum()`, но не получается.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 48 [post_title] => Ответ на вопрос: 'Не санкционированные радары' (id: 4080) [ratings] => 5.00 ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 106 [post_title] => Ответ на вопрос: 'Как снять арест авто?.' (id: 101) [ratings] => 5.00 ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 104 [post_title] => Ответ на вопрос: 'Надавили психологически' (id: 102) [ratings] => 5.00 ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 105 [post_title] => Ответ на вопрос: 'отпуске по уходу за ребенком до 3-х лет' (id: 99) [ratings] => 5.00 ) 
    [4] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 107 [post_title] => Ответ на вопрос: 'Депортировали из Узбекистана. Как вернуться?' (id: 95) [ratings] => 5.00 ) 
    [5] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 49 [post_title] => Ответ на вопрос: 'Пропал табун' (id: 60) [ratings] => 4.43 ) 
    [6] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 71 [post_title] => Ответ на вопрос: 'Ситуация в супермаркете' (id: 69) [ratings] => 4.33 ) 
    [7] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 90 [post_title] => Ответ на вопрос: 'Облагается ли налогом взаиморасчёт?' (id: 89) [ratings] => 4.33 ) 
    [8] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 14 [post_title] => Профиль юриста [ratings] => 4.00 ) 
)
```

Хочу посчитать сумму `[ratings]`

Comment: Просто любопытно. Каждый рейтинг — это среднее значение оценок, отданных за вопрос. А что вам даст сумма рейтингов?

Comment: Даст число который будет сумарным рейтингом для юристов которые ответили на вопросы и за них проголосовали.

Comment: Т.е. за их ответы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;
/**
 * $array - Ваш массив
 */
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $sum += $item->ratings;
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 4):

Исходя из своего богатейшего опыта подозреваю, что считать надо не в массиве, а в **базе данных**

```
SELECT SUM(rating) FROM table WHERE ...
```

Очевидный ответ на любой вопрос вида "как посчитать что-либо в массиве" дан выше.
Если же хочется синтаксического сахару, то если не выпендриваться, и запрашивать данные из БД в виде массива, а не объекта, то

```
array_sum(array_column($array,'ratings'));
```